# Deleting questions after answer provided in comment?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Just right now, I asked a question on Math.SE and I happened to delete it when a user satisfactorily answered it in the comments. The reason is perhaps somewhat immature: I thought the question was extremely basic.

Is this allowed? If it is, is it unethical?

Comment: I think deleting questions for which any answer - in comments or not - has been provided is unethical.

Comment: Okay. I appreciate this response; I understand my mistake.

Comment: Of course this is easily remedied.  If you self-delete a post, you can undelete by yourself as well.

Comment: @hardmath Yes, it has been undeleted.

Comment: It is certainly impolite, but I don't see how it can be called unethical.